# Sinatra/Rack/Bundler application unable to install postgres gem

Tags: postgresql, rubygems, sinatra, bundler, rubymine

I'm trying to install the postgres gem "pg" in my rack/bundler app and keep failing when attempting to install through RubyMine.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable (2.3.5) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2) 
Using data_objects (0.10.13) 
Using dm-core (1.2.1) 
Using dm-aggregates (1.2.0) 
Using dm-constraints (1.2.0) 
Using dm-migrations (1.2.0) 
Using fastercsv (1.5.5) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using json_pure (1.8.0) 
Using multi_json (1.8.2) 
Using dm-serializer (1.2.2) 
Using dm-timestamps (1.2.0) 
Using dm-transactions (1.2.0) 
Using stringex (1.5.1) 
Using uuidtools (2.1.4) 
Using dm-types (1.2.2) 
Using dm-validations (1.2.0) 
Using datamapper (1.2.0) 
Using dm-do-adapter (1.2.0) 
Installing do_postgres (0.10.13) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpq... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adam419/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
    --with-pgsql-server-dir
    --without-pgsql-server-dir
    --with-pgsql-server-include
    --without-pgsql-server-include=${pgsql-server-dir}/include
    --with-pgsql-server-lib
    --without-pgsql-server-lib=${pgsql-server-dir}/
    --with-pgsql-client-dir
    --without-pgsql-client-dir
    --with-pgsql-client-include
    --without-pgsql-client-include=${pgsql-client-dir}/include
    --with-pgsql-client-lib
    --without-pgsql-client-lib=${pgsql-client-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
Could not find PostgreSQL build environment (libraries & headers): Makefile not created


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/do_postgres-0.10.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam419/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/do_postgres-0.10.13/ext/do_postgres/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing do_postgres (0.10.13), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install do_postgres -v '0.10.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So for some reason, with my current project, if I install a gem through the command line it doesn't get added to the External Libraries folder in Rubymine, and have so far been relying on it's own bundle/gem installer. So from reading other questions, I saw to download the Postgres93 support for Mac os x and in the command line I attempted to install postgres gem by specifying the path to the pg_config file, and it downloaded successfully, but didn't get added to the libraries in the project in Rubymine.

```
sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

The above command worked, but didn't cause the gem to appear in Rubymine, and thus I am still unable to push to Heroku. So when attempting to give the additional arguments to the bundle installer I get syntax errors when entering in

```
--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Now the sudo gem install pg with the arguments doesn't even work.

Answer (score -1):

Solution -- Reinstalled Postgresql with homebrew